# AppleScript returning Null()

Tags: applescript

When I run this AppleScript I'm getting the error (null). The only thing I can think of is that the file path is not formatted correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
on run {input, parameters}

    set picFolder to alias "Users:cd:Dropbox (Personal):Camera Uploads:"
    set screenshotFolder to alias "Users:cd:Dropbox (Personal):Camera Uploads:Screenshots:"

    tell application "System Events"
        set photos to path of files of picFolder whose kind is "Portable Network Graphics image"
    end tell

    set screenshots to {}
    repeat with imgPath in photos
        set imgAlias to alias imgPath
        tell application "Image Events"
            set img to open imgPath
            if ((dimensions of img = {640, 1136}) or (dimensions of img = {640, 960}) or (dimensions of img = {1024, 768})) then
                set end of screenshots to imgAlias
            end if
            close img
        end tell
    end repeat

    tell application "Finder"
        move screenshots to screenshotFolder
    end tell


    return input
end run
```

Answer (score 0):

The main script works for me, but not if I run it the way it is in my script editor. I have to comment out `{input, parameters}` and `return input`, because a run handler (in this context) can't accept parameters (or you can change the name of the handler). If I do that there doesn't seem to be a problem (aside from obvious lack of error correction, e.g. if file already exists, etc). You *can* use parameters for a run handler, but you can't test it in the script editor that way (I'm assuming you want to send parameters eventually from the command line).

Comment: @user3439894. Your "improvements" to my answers are most often either a repetition or diversion of users from the meaning of the answer. Again, in this case, since the OP has set the parameters, it means that he is not interested in your script editor, but in the Automator service. Therefore, my recommendations are specific to the service.

Comment: The same for the other user's comment. Nobody cares about your Script Editor. My suggestions for syntax improvements are for getting the service to work. And so that it works not only for me.

Answer (score 0):

Grant to Image Events Full Disk Access.

and replace

```
set img to open imgPath
```

with

```
set img to open file imgPath
```

After

```
tell application "Image Events"
```

add

```
launch
```

Comment: At the time the OP was posted **OS X 10.10 Yosemite** was the latest release and **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Full Disk Access** didn't exist. Even today under e.g. **macOS Big Sur** 11.6 it is not required to give **Full Disk Access** to **Image Events** for this script to work. Also, the other answer stated "The main script works for me, but not if I run it the way it is in my script editor. I have to comment out `{input, parameters`} and `return input`", which of course is to be expected if run in **Script Editor**.

Comment: So, in fact the _primary code_ in the OP does indeed work as written back then and does not require anything that you've mentioned in your answer in that time period. I tested the _code_ under **OS X Yosemite** and it worked as is. (Obviously changing `:cd:` as appropriate.) As a matter of fact, testing in **macOS Catalina** and **macOS Big Sur**, sans what was previously mentioned, the only change I had to make was `whose kind is "Portable Network Graphics image"` to `whose kind is "PNG image"` and the _primary code_ ran without issue and moved that target **PNG** _files_ as coded otherwise.

Comment: I tested on clean installs of each **OS** only giving **Script Editor** privileges under **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and in all three it worked as it was supposed to without doing any of what was is in your answer. So obviously the issue for the OP lies elsewhere.

Comment: @user3439894. Yes, I understand you for a long time. Your statement means that the OP is lying, everything works for him, and my syntax corrections are useless.